# I want my player to move while the button is pressed

Tags: python-3.x, pygame, game-physics, atari-2600

So when i do movement only at one side, it works but once i finish them all, it doesn't work. I tried to switch the numbers, commands, but it was useless. I'm a begginer and my skills are not too good for this because I was using tutorials before. i wanted to do something by myself and not using tutorials for that so i decided to aska quiestion

```
import pygame
import sys
from pygame.locals import *

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

pygame.init()

pygame.display.set_caption("Neverout")
player = pygame.image.load("player.png")

green = (181, 231, 29)

WINDOW_SIZE = (800, 800)

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(WINDOW_SIZE, 0, 32)

player_pos = [385, 50]

up = False #So here I have my movement variables
down = False
right = False
left = False

while True:

    screen.blit(player, player_pos)

    #Here i check if my movement variable are true after I press them

    if left is True:
        player_pos[0] -= 5
    if right is True:
        player_pos[0] += 5
    if up is True:
        player_pos[1] -= 5
    if down is True:
        player_pos[1] += 5

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        #here i check if the button is pressed
        if event.type == KEYDOWN:
            if pygame.K_LEFT:
                left = True
            if pygame.K_RIGHT:
                right = True
            if pygame.K_UP:
                up = True
            if pygame.K_DOWN:
                down = True
        #Here I check if a button is not pressed
        if event.type == KEYUP:
            if pygame.K_LEFT:
                left = False
            if pygame.K_RIGHT:
                right = False
            if pygame.K_UP:
                up = False
            if pygame.K_DOWN:
                down = False
        #Checks for quiting the app
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()
    #No dates only updates
    pygame.display.update()
    screen.fill(green)
    clock.tick(60)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're code is almost correct, it's just checking the events incorrectly.  You need to check `event.key` is equal to the key-code your checking.

The existing code just says things like:

```
if pygame.K_LEFT:
```

But `pygame.K_LEFT` is just a number, like saying `if 27:` which is always True.

Just add the `event.key` in there to fix it:

```
if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
```

Also don't forget to use `elif` (else if), as it's more efficient. If the key event is, say LEFT, it *can't* be RIGHT too, so there's no need to check any other codes.  You can skip checking them with `if .. elif`.

Applying these fixes to your main loop makes the player move OK:

```
for event in pygame.event.get():
    #here i check if the button is pressed
    if event.type == KEYDOWN:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            left = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            right = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            up = True
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            down = True
    #Here I check if a button is not pressed
    elif event.type == KEYUP:
        if event.key == pygame.K_LEFT:
            left = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT:
            right = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_UP:
            up = False
        elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN:
            down = False
    #Checks for quiting the app
    elif event.type == QUIT:
        pygame.quit()
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: It was very helpful